# When writing a CPU emulator, how do you choose between simulating a 16, 32, or 64 bit processor?

Tags: emulation, cpu

If I were to write a really simple CPU Emulator, how would you determine how many bits it is, i.e 16 bits or 32 bits?

Comment: Why would anybody write a simulator for less than 64 bits?  It's not the 80s.

Comment: Good reason.  Which one would be more fun - 16 or 32 bits?  Are 32 bits 2X the fun?

Comment: @duffymo I have no idea.

Comment: Humor isn't your strong suit, I see.

Comment: It's a rarity round here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking a processor is characterised by its register size (machine word size). A 16 bit processor would typically have 16 bit registers, a 16 bit data bus and a 16 bit address bus (capable of addressing 64 kB of memory). It would make one memory access to read/write a register.

However, there are examples of other setups. For example the Intel 8088 CPU was a 16 bit processor with an 8 bit data bus and a 20 bit address bus (capable of addressing 1024 kB of memory). It did two memory accesses to read/write a register, and combined 16 bit segment registers and 16 bit offset registers into a full 20 bit address.

Answer (score 2):

Now it all depend what you want to do with your CPU.

- Is it for self-learning purpose ?

  - Take a cpu with a simple architecture
  - Take a cpu which is commonly used (eg: lot of documentation, can use third part binary to test your emulator etc...)
- You want to use the CPU for a specific purpose ?

  - I started with an 8 bit processor for doing a gameboy emulator.
    (here is the spec if you want to try: http://problemkaputt.de/pandocs.htm)

First define your need/goal, then choose appropriatly which one is fitted for yourself.